# excel group with hidden rows

Tags: excel, vba, outline

I have an Excel sheet where several rows are grouped together using "Group and outline".

By default the group is to be expanded but I have one row that I have hidden using vba in Workbook_Open.

After I click the [-] to collapse the group and then the [+] to expand it again my hidden row is now visible.

Is there a way to keep the hidden row hidden even after the group is collapsed and expanded again? Or is there a way to capture an event so that I can use vba to hide the row every time the group is expanded?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From a link on another site [Excel VBA Trap the Group and Outline expand/collapse (Show Detail / Hide Detail) events](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Visual_Basic/Q_23524127.html)

What it states is

> the only event you can trigger with a
>   group collapse/expand action is the
>   calculation event. To do so you need
>   to use the SUBTOTAL function which is
>   aware of whether or not rows are
>   hidden.

I hope this helps you

Comment: Just a quick tip for others, make sure to hook into the Calculate event and not the Change event which I was doing first otherwise it won't work.